# Moving form resource files to a resource dll

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, resx

I want to move the localized resource files, created for my various winforms, to a resource dll. Is there an easy way to do it, that don't include manually reading every single string from the dll for each form, just like the forms usually handles it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it'll be that difficult, you just have to create a new project of type class library and move your resource file to that project, when you build that project it'll create the dll and then you just need to refer this dll to your actual project and done.

Comment: I did just that with one of my forms but I get an error message when I try to open it.

Comment: Whats the error message, and one more thing did you add the reference in your form, see if intellisense appears while you are refering resources, if it did then it'll be ok.

Comment: The error message is: "Could not find any resource appropriate for the specified culture or the natural culture. Make sure _resource file_ was correctly embedded or linked into assembly _assemblyName_ at compile time or that all satellite assemblies required are loadable or fully signed."  I've added a reference to the dll in my main project, but since it has no namespace or code in it other the resource files I can't see it in the intellisense on the form itself.

Comment: It must have the namespace, bydefault it is same as the project name of your resource library, to make it more easier, right click on the resource string and find the option, resolve, it will automatically add the required namespaces(if you add the reference of your resource lbrary project in current working project)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your solution. The resource dll does have a default namespace but after adding it as a refrence to the main project and clicking it, theat namespace does not show in the object browser under the the assembly name.