# How can I have my C# Form resources in one DLL, whilst the implementing code is in another DLL?

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, localization, resources

I have a project that contains a number of DLL files that contain Form resources which all go through translation/localisation (l10n).

For example, a DLL includes SomeForm.cs, which includes plenty of code functionality. The DLL also contains tranlsated versions of SormForm:  SomeForm.resx, SomeForm.fr.resx and SomeForm.ja.resx (Default Language, French and Japanese translations).

The localisation group has asked for all of the resources to be placed into one library to reduce their overhead.

**How can I move the form resources to a single DLL whilst keeping the code that implements the form in it's current DLL?**

I don't want to move the functionality/code to a single DLL, which I think is what's being suggested here: [Moving form resource files to a resource dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975305/moving-form-resource-files-to-a-resource-dll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Satellite Assemblies**

Satellite assemblies are dll's which only contain resource files.

MSDN Article is very confusing. This article should give you a good understanding about the concept.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/59193/Localizing-a-Windows-Application-with-Satellite-As

**Edit:** Dynamic Layout for windows forms.

[How to: Support Localization on Windows Forms Using AutoSize and the TableLayoutPanel Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1zkt8b33%28v=vs.80%29)

[Walkthrough: Creating a Layout That Adjusts Proportion for Localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k9fa71y%28v=vs.80%29)

**Code Listing**
[How to: Design a Windows Forms Layout that Responds Well to Localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcky5b93%28v=vs.80%29)

Comment: I am using satellite assemblies, which are built from the translated resx files in the project.

Having read that article, and reviewed the authors sample code, I see that he's not actually moved the forms resources directly - i.e. the Form doesn't use Localizable=True and the Language=XYZ etc.

Is it possible to move the form resources with Localizable=True? Or do I need to update all my forms to be based Localizable=False and set the UI elements contents from a string table etc.?

This approach doesn't allow for different sized forms or layout differences between languages (for example)

Comment: I don't think form.fr.resx can be packaged into a new custom dll. RESX files are not a good solution for an adjustable layout. TableLayoutPanel is. Answer is updated.